# Filter CVEs by affected OS

Tags: vulnerability, operating-systems, known-vulnerabilities, cve

Is it possible to filter CVEs by affected platform/OS?

Some sources do provide this, like exploit-db, but the main vulnerability source NVD, National Vulnerability Database, doesn't seem to have such category or filter for neither CVEs or CPEs. Is this to be expected or am I missing something?

If this is not possible or reliable, how could I know if a product is affected by a vulnerability on a specific platform? Should I just assume all of them are affected?

Comment: Do you mean a product with a CVE? Like Adobe Reader? And you want to filter Adobe Reader CVEs based on OS?

Comment: Basically yes. For example, I want to get all CVEs that affect Adobe Reader on Windows specifically, and filter out Linux/macOS, so I could check if the Adobe Reader version I have on my Windows machine is affected.

Comment: That tends not to be relevant. If a product has a vulnerability, it tends not to matter what OS it runs on, or the product is OS-specific. What cross-platform product do you have in mind?

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR Technically yes, it is possible, using some CPE fields. But in practice, this very rarely work.

You use CPE to make requests in the NVD (i.e. not a free text search). Look here for a short introduction to CPE:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Platform_Enumeration#Scheme_Format

We can see that we have a <sw_edition> and a <target_sw> fields available. These are intended for your use case.

On your Acrobat Reader example, these CPE exist in the NVD and make use of such fields:

```
cpe:2.3:a:adobe:acrobat_reader:*:*:*:*:*:android:*:*
cpe:2.3:a:adobe:acrobat_reader:*:*:for_mac_os_x:*:*:*:*:*
cpe:2.3:a:adobe:acrobat_reader:11.0.5:-:*:*:*:windows:*:*
cpe:2.3:a:adobe:acrobat_reader:3.0:*:mac_os_x:*:*:*:*:*
cpe:2.3:a:adobe:acrobat_reader:4.0:*:for_mac_os_x:*:*:*:*:*
cpe:2.3:a:adobe:acrobat_reader:5.0.9:*:unix:*:*:*:*:*
cpe:2.3:a:adobe:acrobat_reader:8.1:*:windows:*:*:*:*:*
```

etc. But there are 2 problems:

1. These <sw_edition> and a <target_sw> field are rarely used. There are maybe 12-15 occurrences of these, for the 200+ existing CPE for Acrobat Reader.
2. There is no canonical form for these. In the example above we can see both
   "for_mac_os_x" and "mac_os_x", depending on the mood of the reporter,
   or the NVD analyst.

TL;DR CPE are both over-designed and underused. As for myself, I just use the first field cpe:<cpe_version>::::, everything past these is more or less chaos. I also keep a full list of the 350.000+ existing CPE for quick grep searching.

In the NVD you can search per CPE here:
https://nvd.nist.gov/products/cpe/search

Using one of the example CPE above `cpe:2.3:a:adobe:acrobat_reader:11.0.5:-:*:*:*:windows:*:*` you'll get to:
https://nvd.nist.gov/products/cpe/search/results?namingFormat=2.3&keyword=cpe%3A2.3%3Aa%3Aadobe%3Aacrobat_reader%3A11.0.5%3A-%3A*%3A*%3A*%3Awindows%3A*%3A*

...that will lead you to:
https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/search/results?form_type=Advanced&results_type=overview&isCpeNameSearch=true&seach_type=all&query=cpe:2.3:a:adobe:acrobat_reader:11.0.5:-:*:*:*:windows:*:*

And then, good luck with that.

But for example, from the obtained list of CVE, this one has some platform/OS information (scroll to the bottom, look at the "Running on/with":
https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2017-11307

CPE matching is a *very* complicated topic. For more information, see "Known Affected Software Configurations" here: https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/vulnerability-detail-pages

The full CPE specifications - there are several, it's actually a stack - are available here: https://csrc.nist.gov/projects/security-content-automation-protocol/specifications/cpe